# jquery .hide() and show() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

I have IE 11 and when i try this code, it works in firefox and chrome but not in IE, is there any workaround?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});
$(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Comment: Do you mean that your `p` element is not hiding or showing in IE11? I can not repeat your problem: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2aafu7w/)

Comment: Work fine with my explorer too

Comment: Did you check if IE is blocking the loading of the external JQuery script ? Can you use any other JQuery functions successfully ?  Your example works fine in IE10

Comment: And try to avoid of specifying protocol for CDN-links. I.e.: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your script in multiple versions of IE and the script is even working in old versions like IE 5.

Like mentioned earlier by some others, make sure IE isn't blocking external files.